# Perl LSB Steganography Script

Tags: perl, steganography

I have been looking at a small sample Perl script present by Andrew Ker that performs LSB steganography in PGM and PPM files. (accessed - http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/andrew.ker/docs/ADK11B.pdf)

The script presented is as follows (running on Ubuntu Linux):

```
perl -n0777 <cover-image > stego-image 
    -e’split/(\s+)/,<STDIN>,5;@z=map ord,split"",pop@_;srand key; for(0..$#z){@p[$k,$_]=($_,$p[$k=int rand$_]);} map{$z[$q=shift@p]+=($z[$q]-ord()&1)*(rand 2<=>1)} split"",unpack"B*",$_;print@_,map chr,@z;’ secret-text-ﬁle
```

However, this gives a syntax error for me, which I think is from the use of the ’ character. I have no experience with Perl, so I am slowing trying to figure out what the problem might be.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the character `’` was converted by whatever word processing program this PDF was created. It's supposed to be a single quote `'`. Replace both instances and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I made these changes and was given the following error: Bareword found where operator expected at test.prl line 3, near "secret-text" (Missing operator before secret-text?)

Comment: @jr791 why is there a _test.pl_ file involved? You are supposed to run this on the command line directly. `perl` is the Perl interpreter command. See https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=perl+-n0777+%3Ccover-image+%3E+stego-image+-e%27...%27+secret-text-%EF%AC%81le

Comment: @jr791, If `secret-text` is seen as part of the Perl code, you did not simply replace the two `’` with `'` as you should have.